# inserting text inside a node katalon

Tags: text, set, katalon-studio

I am trying to insert a text inside a P tag dynamically.

```
WebUI.waitForElementPresent(findTestObject('Page_Mthode Swing - EidosMedia QA_m (1)/span_Insert Headline Here'), 10)

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Page_Mthode Swing - EidosMedia QA_m (1)/span_Insert Headline Here'), 'Testing Katalon')

span_Insert Headline Here - xpath: id("editor_1")/eom-content/div[@class="xsm-doc"]/div[@class="xsm-story"]/div[@class="xsm-grouphead emxed-ct-headline emxed-contentitem-wrapper"]/div[@class="xsm-headline"]/p[@class="xsm-p"]
```

desired output: `p tag Testing /p`

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: `HTML <p>` tag is not an input field, it contains predefined text.